# How can I access Ubuntu from Windows 8?

Tags: grub2

I've dual booted my laptop with Ubuntu-13.04 and windows 8

While I am in windows-8, is there any way by which I can boot installed UBUNTU in virtual machine, or any that kind of Software?

- I just don't want to restart my PC to boot in Ubuntu
- I don't mean to access storage partition
- I just want to BOOT into UBUNTU (which is pre installed) in Windows-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you've got Ubuntu and Windows in dual boot and you want to access run Ubuntu from inside Windows too? Do you still want dual boot?

The simplest way would be to just have a separate install of Ubuntu inside a VM (virtual machine) in Windows, using something like VirtualBox.

If you want access to the same install from within Windows, that should be possible too - but it's a lot less tested. [VirtualBox can give a VM access to a partition](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk) and through that you should be able to boot. The VBox website says this can be risky so make sure any data in the Ubuntu partition is backed up somewhere.

If you don't need to be able to dual-boot, I'd be tempted to ditch the bare-metal Ubuntu install and just set up a standard VM.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to access your alredy installed ubuntu partition while on windows.

For simultaneously running both OS, you need to install ubuntu (or windows if host os is ubuntu) in some virtual machine like vmware or virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

If your running Windows 8 and want to run Ubuntu on a Virtual machine you should use the new Windows 8 Hyper-V.

But your Hardware have to meat certain requirements to run Hyper-V. Check here:

***64-bit PCs only.*** Like the Server software on which it is based, Client Hyper-V only runs on 64-bit PCs that are running the 64-bit version of Windows 8 Pro (or Enterprise).*

***Chipset requirements.*** *Client Hyper-V requires modern Intel and AMD microprocessors that include Second Level Address Translation (SLAT) technologies. Fortunately, this is a feature of all current generation (“Sandy Bridge” on Intel) microprocessors. But it means that your older Core 2 Duo-based PCs may not work.*

***Memory.*** *Your PC must be configured with at least 4 GB of RAM. Of course, more is always better with virtualization, so if your needs are high-end, you’ll want more RAM than that.*

Source: [Windows 8 Feature Focus: Client Hyper-V](http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/windows-8-feature-focus-client-hyper-v)

Go to "Turn Windows features on or off" and check if you can enable Hyper-V.

You you don't have the required hardware use [VirualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [Vmware](http://www.vmware.com/products/player) instead.